# Do Mapbox maps display inline in Tweets?

Tags: mapbox

All,

As per [this link](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-twitter-embed/), does Twitter still support inline display of Mapbox maps?

Following the tutorial and testing it out myself, I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What sort of link are you including? I just tested it with a recent search hit on `tiles.mapbox.com` and got this, which shows for me in browser:

https://twitter.com/neogeografen/status/450725638690054146

Comment: Trying to post a link from this map: https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/openingofdetroit.hiahfhl3/page.html?secure=1#14/42.3299/-83.0812 From what I can see, all looks fine but not showing up when posting link via tweet. Thanks!

Comment: @incanus - yeah, but isn't that twitter link just showing an image of a map (not an actual slippy map)?